# Is the quest for a theory unifying gravity and quantum mechanics just wishful thinking?

Tags: quantum-gravity, theory-of-everything, unified-theories

What is the basis of the believe that there should be a unified theory which simultaneously gives quantum physics (the regime small things moving very fast) and gravity (the regime of big things moving very slowly)? Is this just wishful thinking?

Are there any people who make a strong case of the possibility that no such theory can exist?

This is a sincere question. Please don't throw stones at me.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146065/discussion-on-question-by-dohmatob-is-the-quest-for-a-theory-unifying-gravity-an); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

I just have a very general answer. By wishful thinking, do you mean being misled by a desire for a certain outcome? The desire to come up with a theory is certainly there. But there are reasons to think the approach taken is reasonable. And there is no consensus that success is guaranteed.

There are 4 known forces. There is some behavior that follows patterns. So far mathematical models have been very successful at capturing the patterns and reducing them to laws. It is very reasonable to expect math to be up to the job of capturing the full behavior. We may or may not be smart enough to do the job. We may or may not ever be able to perform experiments that would give us data needed to make progress. A final theory may or may not take the form we expect.